# Apache POI WorkbookFactory.create throws java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, apache-poi, spreadsheet, google-app-engine

My issue is pretty simple. I want to validate files up to 50MB in size for correct formatting in App Engine.

This presents a number of large challenges now. The first of which is the Apache XLS/XLSX POI API. When I load 20MB of file data into memory **locally** before validation it throws:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2271)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:140)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource$FakeZipEntry.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:128)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:55)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:84)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:272)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:79)
```

I need to open and valite spreadsheets up to 20 to 25MB in size. 50 would be a nice stretch goal if possible. We're talking hundreds of thousands of lines of data all on a single sheet.

Now my traditional code loads the entire file into memory and promptly proceeds to crash the heap of my app engine instance. Here's my traditional code:

```
    public ErrorLog validateWorkbook(inputWorkbook)
    {
        int sheetCount = inputWorkbook.getNumberOfSheets();
        for (int x = 0; x< sheetCount; x++)
        {
            Sheet currentSheet = inputWorkbook.getSheetAt(x);
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = currentSheet.rowIterator();
            while(rowIterator.hasNext())
            {
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = rowIterator.next().cellIterator();
                while(cellIterator.hasNext())
                {
                    Cell currentCell = cellIterator.next();
                    boolean success = validateCellContents(currentCell);
                    if(!success)
                        ErrorLog.appendError(new Error()); // detailed user error explicitly defining error location, cell value, and recommended steps to fix
                }
            }
        }
        return ErrorLog;
    }
```

Now there are supposedly event-based ways to handle an actionlistener every time a cell is encountered. But the dummy code [here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/extractor/XSSFEventBasedExcelExtractor.java) has a reference to:

```
ReadOnlySharedStringsTable strings = new ReadOnlySharedStringsTable(container);
```

I've inspected this object in the debugger and it contains every unique string reference in the current worksheet. This is essentially doing exactly what I'm trying to avoid. It's allocating a large block of memory to store each value in memory beforehand. The ideal solution takes a stream of input bytes and decodes the strings as it traverses the file to reduce the memory footprint.

Because the string table is definitely going to take up a lot of space in memory. I'm working on processing 150,000 to 300,000 line item spreadsheets

Now the [quick guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) mentions that you can use a *File* or *InputStream* and that if you use a File, the input will be buffered. The problem here being that App Engine and the Blob Store Service, have no knowledge of File Objects and only return InputStreams (to the best of my knowledge).

Additionally, the other event-driven model, [Default Handler](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/examples/FromHowTo.java), doesn't seem to have any concept of a column or row for each value in its interface-defined methods that are called when actions take place (and it also allocates the entire Shared String Table up front).

Running out of ideas here! Gonna try to offer up a bounty for this. At least a concrete 'no this isn't possible' would suffice and then I can start looking at workarounds but I get the feeling I'm just not using the vast API as well as I could be.

Comment: I've modified my eclipse.ini to increase the amount of memory but the server is still erroring out rather quickly. I know how to increase the memory of a tomcat instance but not a local app engine server instance. I believe that's where the error is occuring.

Comment: If memory is a concern, why not use the [XSSF streaming SAX read API](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api) rather than the regular XSSF usermodel? The former is streaming and low memory, latter is much easier but DOM-like so higher memory

Comment: This looks good but quite a bit more complex than the other API! Thanks for the link, I'll check it out tomorrow at work!

Comment: If it was easy everyone would use it... You can either throw some more memory at your server so you can use the easy usermodel (if Google let you do that?), or go the hard way....

Comment: So I've implemented the event based API but the output doesn't seem to make any sense. Every string value is prepended with what appears to be logical coordinates but the values don't match up to those from the spreadsheet: C2 - REQUIRED but the value in C2 in the spreadsheet is not "REQUIRED". Any idea what's going on here? I realize after a bit of research that the event based API is reactionary but it doesn't seem to be able to easily correlate cell values to their coordinates which seems fundamental to me in parsing spreadsheets.

Comment: Apache POI ships with several good examples of using the XSSF Event API and the HSSF Event API, I can only suggest you compare your code to those and see what you're doing differently. It's perfectly possible to get the value of a cell as it goes past, as well as spot "missing" cells, as the examples show!

Comment: Is there a better example than http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/examples/FromHowTo.java ?? When parser.parse(inputstream) executes the output makes 0 sense. I know the private static sheethandler class is doing all the printing but still. For instance the word row or column is not mentioned once at all in that code. After reading through the code 15 times it doesn't seem to give any indication of being self aware at all, more that it's just processing stream bytes as they come in and converting them to String objects.

Comment: [XSSFEventBasedExcelExtractor](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/extractor/XSSFEventBasedExcelExtractor.java) is another suggestion. Each cell xml element comes with the cell's reference as an attribute, from that you can get row and column, or you can track it yourself

Comment: This looks a lot better @Gagravarr thanks so much! I'm going to write an answer to help better format the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advocate,

You **can** do this,
 but you'll have to get creative to get around some of GAE's limitations.

First, App engine front end instances have a 1 minute limit to request, so if you want to process files as big as 50 mb you'll be forced to use either [task queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/queue) or using "[Manual/basic scaling module](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/)" to escape that time constraint.

Second, Memory. Here again you have 2 choices, [Using modules](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/) you have a better control over your instances memory, which is a step in the right direction but it won't scale as good.

I have been in your situation and I ended up using the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/) +[Google Spreadheets API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) or the [Blobstore service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/) depending on the requirements. Using either of those alternatives I uploaded the excel files so i could process them in batches offline using queues.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer @jirungaray!! Unfortunately I'm not on the project anymore though. But i'll keep your solution in mind for future opportunities and I've marked it as the correct answer :)

I think the key here is uploading the spreadsheet, breaking it up, and processing it in chunks so the instance doesn't run out of memory as you said.